# Hero that can solo Roshan at an early level aside from Ursa

Tags: dota-2, dota

Aside from Ursa, is there any hero that can solo Roshan at an early level, like level 6 or at least below level 10?

Comment: This is not a duplicate since were talking about SOLOing Roshan, not by a TEAM

Comment: ... Fair enough.

Comment: I don't play that much DOTA anymore, but I think it was possible with LifeStealer, and the druid champion that has a bear companion (I forgot his name)

Comment: @MegaNairda Did you even read the answer to that question? Lycan, Enigma, Ursa, Venomancer, and Syllabear, all heroes listed as effective Roshan killers, are easily capable of soloing him from levels 6-10. I get the questions are different, but the answer remains almost exactly the same.

Comment: @Kotsu The same attributes help, but one that's more emphasized when soloing is lifesteal. Having the ability to sustain tankiness for quite a bit helps, too.

Comment: Also soloing roshan doesn't quickly raise a suspicion when one hero is missing on the map, thus your enemies might not even notice the probability of you soling roshan until roshan's dead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Asides from Ursa, some of the better heroes for soloing Roshan from levels 6-10 are:

- **Enigma**: Using Eidolons and a Medallion of Courage. You may also need a Soul Ring to keep your mana pool up. The idea here is to cast cast Medallion on him to reduce his armor to greatly increase your Eidolons' DPS. As MadCom mentions below, Medallion doesn't proc Roshan's spell shield so you don't have to worry about him blocking it.
- **Nature's Prophet**: Using Treants and a Medallion of Courage. Use Sprout in the Roshan pit for trees to use. A Ring of Basilius will help your Treants tank Roshan more easily.
- **Shadow Shaman**: Using Mass Serpent Wards. With careful placement of the wards by the edge of the Roshan pit, you can kite Roshan with your hero as the wards hit him.
- **Venomancer**: Using Plague Wards. Like with Shadow Shaman's wards, kiting Roshan is the key. Plague Wards used to block Roshan so you could create a wall between him and Venomancer, but that is no longer the case.
- **Lycan**: Using his wolves and a Vladimir's Offering. Shift aggro appropriately to tank damage.
- **Lone Druid**: Using his bear and a Vladimir's Offering. Shift aggro appropriately to tank damage.
- **Troll Warlord**: With points into Fervor and Battle Trance and either Vladimir's Offering or a Helm of the Dominator. It's also recommended you switch into melee form for faster attack speed, health, and damage (also, Vladimir's Offering wouldn't work if you were in ranged form anyways).

Comment: You don't need to use Malefice. Medalion doesn't proc Roshan's spell shield (also Linken).

Comment: @MadCom Good to know, edited my answer.

Comment: Please add Troll Warlord to this list. With Fervor at level 3 or 4 and Battle Trance at level 2 it is possible to do him at level 11 solo.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic OP asked for heroes who can solo him from levels 6-10.

Comment: At level 10 it is still possible yet dependent on the RNG whether you get stunned too often. The second point in Battle Trance can help though it is not necessary.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic I've edited my answer.

Comment: I would add furion with sprout block into treant + medaillon. Shadow Shaman with mass serpent wards can take down rosh solo very early aswell.

Comment: Veno's wards do not block roshan anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I agree drow can easily do rosh with lifesteal after level 6 but its risky and takes awhile. 
For pub games under 3k; Ursa can solo rosh at level 3 or 4 with 2 stout shields and a morbid mask. skill build should be 0 2 2. lvl 3 is risky as its dependent on how many bashes roshan gets but lvl 4 is guaranteed.
Juggernaut can solo rosh after he gets a MOM and atleast 900hp with points going towards healing wards and crit.
PA can do the same as Jug at lvl 9 with max blur and some kind of tanking/hp item like pms, 4 gauntlets etc. you could stop in between and salve up if rosh gets too many bashes.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Troll Warlord can solo roshan, just use and use his rampage.

Answer (score 2):

Invoker is able to with 4 points into Quas and Exort for double forge spirits.

He has to have his units all split the damage taken.

Here is a video where the guy buys Helm of the Dominator.

And controls a 4th guy to tank it.

It's more efficient to buy a medallion for the - armor and 2 or 3 salves (tank with your hero until half health, then heal up while minions split damage) since Invoker doesn't hit hard enough for a Satanic to be worthwhile. Also medallion is usable on enemy heroes who die extremely fast then to forge spirit focus fire.

Answer (score 1):

Try Drow. If you have a well equipped L8+ Drow, she can kite and kill Roshan. You need to rush in and start pelting Roshan with ice arrows (Drow's orb). When Roshan gets too close, back off and let it retreat. Then attack it again. Repeat till dead.

Comment: If Roshan can be stunned, couldn't Sniper do it just as easily? How much chasing mobs slow down due to Drow's orb is roughly the same as how much mobs slow down due to mini-stuns from Sniper.

Comment: Drow's ultimate is what really makes the difference here, which applies to most of her attacks and makes each attack all the more powerful. Sniper has stun, but the per move attack is not that high at early levels.

Comment: I forgot about Drow's ultimate, yes her damage should be higher and she will clear quicker.

Comment: The enemy team is likely to spot you if you have to kite ...

Comment: If Drow has lifesteal from MOM or Helm she can easily tank it from lvl 8 if you have 4 points in [e]

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to solo Roshan with **Nature's Prophet** at level 10. Although it's not been as quick and easy as soloing it with Ursa.
At level 10 you should have ability points spent like this:

- Sprout : 2
- Teleportation : 3
- Nature's Call : 4
- Wrath of Nature : 1

And you should have bought **Ring of Basilius** (that adds an armor bonus aura to nearby allies) in order to give a slightly more armor bonus to your Treant.
The generic tactic is using your Treants to tank Roshan, and with Nature's Call at level 5, you can spawn 5 Treants every 37 seconds. Also you can combo-cast Sprout and Nature's Call in order to position your Treants faster.
Otherwise, if you would like to save more mana, you can move in the nearby jungle and cast Ns'C there, then moving into Roshan with your trees.
It will take some time to kill Roshan this way, but you could be able to do it without moving back to the base to recover your mana.

Answer (score 1):

Rasta can easily kill rosh at level 6. If you can put the wards nicely (able to block him) then you can just go  near him and then attack rosh. What happens is rosh will try to attack you (not the wards). But you are out of his range so he will just keep tryin to attack you until he dies.

Comment: This is only true for DotA1. In DotA2 you can no longer trap roshan with Plague Wards [Source](http://www.dota2.com/newbloom/day2/)

Comment: *shadow Shaman.

Answer (score 1):

A level 6 drow under 8minutes can take Roshan with a MOM quite easily. No kiting needed, just stand at entrance and activate MOM when he turns to run back to maximize effectiveness.
+3 in Aura and +1 in Ult, can probably do with less in aura would just take a bit longer. It can also help to eat a tango before running into the pit.

Answer (score 0):

Veno can solo rosh at lvl 10, without taking damage, with gale lvl2, then wards and sting maxed, you'll need 2 Voidstones and a blink, then all the Clarity pots you can buy and maybe a Manaboot.

Get up on the ridge, start up a clarity, place down wards, use Gale to aggro him and keep it up.

Make sure your stupid teammates dont get into a teamfight while youre doing this, because you wont have enough mana to initiate if you cut off halfway. I'll do it sometime and post the match id, then give the time I start it.

You will not be able to attack  directly while doing it this way, unless you blink around and right click him every 13 seconds, which is faster, but riskier.

Make sure you blink in to get the XP at the end.

Answer (score 0):

best hero to solo roshan very fast is ursa.
He only needs morbid mask to kill roshan.
I could kill roshan with morbid mask in 4th minute of game and my lvl was 4.

Comment: The question clearly says "aside from Ursa".

Answer (score 0):

Ok first I would like to state the obvious heroes that can solo rosh before level 10 as of 6.84:

- **Lycan**

  Lycan is considered the number 2 solo roshan hero after Ursa. With lifesteal you should be able to kill rosh without trouble.
- **Troll Warlord**

  This hero can do it with enough farm. With his ulti and Helm of the dominator, and maybe half a yasha, this hero should be able to take rosh on pretty early.
- **Juggernaut**

  With his healing ward and lifesteal he should definitely be able to solo roshan at level 9.
- **Lifestealer**

  Again with enough farm this should be possible before level 10.
- **Enchantress**

  This might sound weird but if you max [untouchable](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Enchantress#Untouchable), Roshan will have no attack speed at all. You can easily tank this with even a morbid mask(*good item anyway since this hero is build with Mask of Madness sometimes*). Of course you also have nature's attendant and you can have creeps with you in the roshan pit to tank/deal damage. **Trust me this works.**

Now besides this I'd like to state that most heroes with the ability to summon creeps(Nature's prophet, Lone druid, etc) could also solo Roshan before level 10 considering they have normal farm.

Heroes with good farm before level 10 that can solo Roshan are most of the agility carries with lifesteal like Phantom Assassin, Faceless void(maybe) can kill roshan before level 10.

This might not work but I've seen someone actually kill Roshan with Shadow Shaman. Shadow Shaman would get onto the cliff of the roshan pit, summon the serpent wards, use his first ability and then shackle while the serpent wards attack roshan. I dont think this is possible before level 10 since you only have level 1 serpent wards. Just wanted to note this here though.

Answer (score -2):

Ursa just buy valdimers offering and boots then no need to be lv6 just use the OP and the 3rd skill to kill roshan it can damage roshan over 3000 damage per hit