# When can you Roshan solo?

Tags: dota-2

I hope this is not too complex a question and is simple as in: is there a statistical point, like damage taken vs given, when someone can take Roshan?

I understand this gets complicated by other factors like evasion, but assuming things like that aren't factoring in, when can one Rosh alone?

Comment: I ask because I've seen heros do it before I was level six, so I assume it's something any hero can do at some level <25.

Comment: see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106815/hero-that-can-solo-roshan-at-an-early-level-aside-from-ursa

Comment: That question only concerns early roshan though. For other heroes a more general approach for solo rosh can be given but since they are many heroes in dota for which I dont see any point in soloing rosh (mostly hard support) or heroes that common item built doesnt allow solo rosh, this question might be difficult to answer

Comment: @WizLiz Right, seeing it made me realize this question might not be answerable in a paragraph or two. Do you think it's a Q&A Q?

Comment: Roshan increases in power over the course of a game. You need to be able to both out-damage his regeneration and either tank or lifesteal through the damage he can give.

Comment: How is that a duplicate of the given question?

Comment: I think the question to which this is marked as duplicate is 'how' can you solo roshan. This question has a greater emphasis on 'when'. This shouldn't be marked as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

I one sense, this is the same as asking: "When can I solo kill an enemy hero?" When you can reduce their HP to zero faster than they can do the same to you; it's the same for Roshan. I've soloed with Life Stealer using armlet, deso, hyperstone and rage. Armor reduction is very helpful when fighting Roshan, solo or otherwise. Some combination of armor reduction, attack speed and self healing would all be good for a solo attempt. I'd say you really just have to learn this by experience. You could use cheats to set up experiments with different heroes and items.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest measure to understand when you can take on Roshan solo is when you have all your core items + 1 or 2 luxurious items AND have any form of lifesteal. Ofcourse I am talking about Agility heroes here. Supports or tanks cant take on Roshan easily let alone solo.

As an after thought, having a Cranium Basher(Skull Basher) helps a lot too.